# e.pageX and pageY puts tooltip in an odd area

Tags: javascript, svg

I've been looking for a way for a tooltip to sort of hover just above the cursor, I've seen a lot of posts recommending using the event `pageX` and `pageY` coordinates something like this:

```
const showToolTip = (evt, text) => {
  let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = text;
  console.log(evt)
  tooltip.style.visibility = "visible";
  tooltip.style.left = evt.pageX +'px';
  tooltip.style.top = evt.pageY + 'px';
}
```

However, when I do this the tooltip is generally like 400 pixels right of the mouse and 300 pixels below the mouse.

Something to note I'm doing this on an SVG:

```
<div id="tooltip" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"></div>

<svg id="calendar" width="636px" height="84px"></svg>

....

// SVG is made up of several boxes and when one is hovered over the tooltip should appear: 
  box.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {showToolTip(e, day)})
  box.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {hideToolTip()})
  svg.appendChild(box);
}
```

Again all this functionality works and the tooltip appears and moves around but it's just super far away from where the mouse is.  I've tried to offset this by writing something like `tooltip.style.left = (event.pageX - 300) + 'px'` which sort of works but feels hacky and sometimes at different sizes it will do weird things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your tooltip is not in a `relative` container, as that'll make the absolute position relative to that element.

Comment: I just threw an absolute div around the tooltip and SVG to be sure and now it's not showing up at all (although it is console logging so I know the functions working, I'm assuming it's just so far off that it's not appearing in the window).

Comment: Try placing the tooltip as a direct child of `document.body`

Comment: That was it! Thank you.